# How can I get the parameter of a GestureRecognizer command in my view model command method?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a template that checks for a Tap:

```
<Grid.GestureRecognizers>
   <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding TapCommand, Source={x:Reference this}}" CommandParameter="{Binding TapCommandParam, Source={x:Reference this}}" NumberOfTapsRequired="1" />
   </Grid.GestureRecognizers>
```

In the back end I did this to set up the bindings:

```
    public static readonly BindableProperty TapCommandProperty =
        BindableProperty.Create(
            nameof(TapCommand),
            typeof(Command),
            typeof(GridTemplate),
            default(Command));

    public Command TapCommand
    {
        get { return (Command)GetValue(TapCommandProperty); }
        set { SetValue(TapCommandProperty, value); }
    }


    public static readonly BindableProperty TapCommandParamProperty =
        BindableProperty.Create(
            nameof(TapCommandParam),
            typeof(string),
            typeof(GridTemplate),
            default(string));

    public string TapCommandParam
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(TapCommandParamProperty); }
        set { SetValue(TapCommandParamProperty, value); }
    }
```

and I set up the command like this:

```
private ICommand openPageCmd;

    public ICommand OpenPageCmd => openPageCmd ?? (openPageCmd = new Command(() => OpenPage()));

    public void OpenPage()
    {
        // I need the parameter of the command here
    }
```

When the grid is tapped the command is called but how can I access the parameter which is something I would like to use

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Declare your command like this:

```
private ICommand openPageCmd;

public ICommand OpenPageCmd => openPageCmd ?? (openPageCmd = new Command<string>((stringValue) => xx(stringValue)));

public void xx(string stringValue)
{
    var a = 0;
}
```

Comment: In my case the parameter will be a string. I'm a bit confused with YourObject and yourObject.  Could you show me how I should define yourObject for this case? Thanks

Comment: simply replace it by a string :) I'll update my answer.

Comment: Thanks for the very quick response,  I will try that now.